# TSQLQuery and update of data aware components

Tags: c++, sql, vcl, dbexpress

I have a sqlite database containing 'notes' for customers. The database design is quite simple and involves one table for notes, a "link" table, linking, relating customers and notes named customer_note and a customers table. The notes table have an id field, the customer_note have customer_id and note_id (one to many) and the customers table have a id as well.

The query to obtain the notes for a selected customer is:

```
SELECT * FROM note n 
INNER JOIN customer_note cn 
ON (cn.note_id = n.id) 
WHERE customer_id = :customerID 
ORDER BY created_on ASC
```

The query is executed in an event where the customers client dataset is scrolled, i.e.

```
customersCDSAfterScroll()
{
int cID = customerCDS->FieldByName("id")->AsInteger;
customerNotesQ->Params->ParamByName("customerID")->AsInteger = bID;
customerNotesQ->Open();

//Get notes
string note = stdstr(customerNotesQ->FieldByName("note")->AsString);
Log(lInfo) << "Note is: "<<note;
customerNotesQ->Close();
```

}

The query is referenced by a DataSetProvider, a ClientDataSet and a DataSource component. On the UI a TDBLookupListbox is receiving the data.

Problem is, the TDBLookpListbox shows ALL notes for all customers.
In the log messages, from the code above, I can see that the query seem to do its job correctly however.

Any idea on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since the result of the query contains only notes correctly filtered by the param, it is not possible that this query is the one providing data to the listbox.

The answer could therefore be that you have misconfigured DBLookupListBox and assigned another datasource to it, one that points to a query that doesn't filter your notes.

Also we can not see if customerNotesQ really is closed when you assign the param value and open the query. But if not, the param would have no effect.